# MS DOS IF and % percent

Tags: variables, if-statement, parameters, dos

I haven't done DOS in forever and can't recall the idiosyncracies with prefixing labels with %. I'm trying to write a script (others may also find it useful) to connect to ADB to a WiFi service running on my tablet.

```
@echo off
set def=192.168.1.21
if "%1" == "" (
    echo.Please supply the IP address of the ADB server/tablet.
    set /p ip=[%def%]
    if %ip% == "" (
      set ip=%def%
    )
) else (
    set ip=%1
    "C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\platform-tools\adb" connect "%ip":5555
)
```

The script should accept an IP address on the commandline, but if none is supplied, if should prompt the operator. If nothing is entered, the printed, square bracketed default should be used.

It seems to work, except that

```
set ip=%def%
```

never executes. I think I messed up the second IF statement. I just can't get the % signs in the right place!! Does anyone remember this old black magic?

Thanks.

Comment: I seriously doubt you are running MS DOS. DOS is an old operating system that existed prior to windows. You are probably simply using the Command Prompt console on Windows. It looks similar to DOS, but it isn't DOS :)

Comment: I know what you're saying. Nevertheless, the statement remains accurate: I haven't done DOS in forever. This is the same foible from back in the day. I sort of miss it, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to set ip to the default if the user didn't enter anything. SET /P will preserve the existing value if the user presses Enter without typing anything. So all you need to do is set the value to the default before issuing SET /P.

Problems can occur if the user provides quotes for the arguments, and then your code adds additional quotes. It is generally safer to use `"%~1"` - the tilde strips any existing quotes, and then you add your own. This works if the argument is already quoted or not.

You probably should remove any existing quotes when you SET ip in your ELSE statement.

You are missing a % when you attempt to expand ip as an argument to adb. I suspect that you always want to execute the command. Your current code only executes the command if ip is provided as an argument.

I would structure the code as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "def=192.168.1.21"
set "ip=%~1"
if not defined ip (
  set "ip=%def%"
  echo Please supply the IP address of the ADB server/tablet.
  set /p "ip=[%def%] "
)
"C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\platform-tools\adb" connect "%ip%:5555"
```

Comment: Just to clarify the requirement: I was hoping that if the user did not enter a commandline argument, they would be prompted to enter one and that the prompt would display a default, if no IP was entered. In the above solution set /p "ip=[%def%] " won't display the default it it's not been defined.

Comment: You are correct that the command needs to be outside the last bracket. That was "finger trouble"!

Comment: @KDM - Yes, that requirement was my intent, but I had a silly logic error. It should be fixed now.

Comment: YES! Should have spotted that myself. That's a +1 from me. Thanks!